# Find the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the given function at the given value of x.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Find the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the given function at the given value of x. Find the equation of the tangent line. : $y=x^4-5x^3+2; x=2$

I understand that the slope of the line follows the equation of

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h.$$

But I don't know how to go about the rest

Comment: You should read about derivatives.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is MathJax tutorial.  You have a misplaced parenthesis in the "equation".   Have you learned a formula for the derivative of a polynomial?

Comment: *Do I plug in 2 after getting the solution* Yes and you obtain $y'(2)$, the value of the derivative at $a=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the h-method you start with

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{y(a+h)-y(a)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(a+h)^4-5\cdot (a+h)^3+2-(a^4-5\cdot a^3+2)}{h}$$

To resolve  $(a+h)^4$ you can use the binomial theorem: $(x+y)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}x\cdot x^k\cdot y^{n-k}$

$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{a^4+4a^3h+6a^2h^2+4ah^3+h^4-5a^3-15a^2h-15ah^2-5h^3+2-a^4+5\cdot a^3-2}{h}$$

Next we eliminate the terms with opposite signs, e.g. $a^4$ and $-a^4$

$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{4a^3h+6a^2h^2+4ah^3+h^4-15a^2h-15ah^2-5h^3}{h}$$

Factoring out $h$ at the numerator.

$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{h\cdot \left(4a^3+6a^2h+4ah^2+h^3-15a^2-15ah-5h^2\right)}{h}$$

Cancelling $h$

$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}4a^3+6a^2h+4ah^2+h^3-15a^2-15ah-5h^2$$

$$=4a^3-15a^2=y'(a)$$

This is the derivative of $y(x)$ at value $x=a$ and therefore the **slope**. Finally you can insert $a=2$ to obtain $y'(2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest equation is point-slope form because (1) as you observe, the derivative gives this slope and (2) it is very easy to get the $y$-coordinate of a point on the curve given its $x$-coordinate.  So, the line through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ of slope $m$ has the equation
$$  y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)  \text{.}  $$

The above should be enough for you to finish your problem.  If you need more...

> $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x = 4x^3 - 15x^2$.  At x = 2, this evaluates to $4 \cdot 8 - 15 \cdot 4 = -28$, so the slope of the line in question is $-28$.
>  Then, evaluating for $y$ when $x = x_0 = 2$, we have $y_0 = x_0^4 - 5 x_0^3 + 2 = 16 - 5 \cdot 8 + 2 = -22 \text{.}$

Finally, should you still not see how to assemble these three numbers into the equation...

> Then an equation of the line is $$  y - (-22) = -28(x - 2)  \text{,}  $$ although it is easy to clean this up a little, to $$  y + 22 = -28(x - 2)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Did you mean $y-y_0$ where you typed $y=y_0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Yes I did.  Thanks!  Fixed.

Comment: Also, did you mean $22$ when you  typed $32$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Yes.  Yowza; can't type today.  Thanks, again!

Comment: Thank you! This process would change if they asked for a secant line, correct?

Comment: For a secant line, you will have two points on the curve.  Call then $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.  (If you have the $x$s, you can easily get the $y$s.)  Then use point-point form: $$  y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The slope should be the value of the derivative y(x)' at point (2,y(2)), where y(2)=-22.
Read [How to get derivatives of polynomials](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/polynomials.html) for the details , you will learn  ($x^n$)'=n($x^{n-1}$) .

Given  y=$x^4$-5$x^3$+2, $y(x)'$ = $4x^3$-15$x^2$,   y(2)'=-28

From point-slope formula,  the line equation is  y+22=(x-2)(-28),  or   y=-28x+34.